# How to know a mid's name in freebase

Tags: mapping, freebase

I have recently got a freebase dumps,but there is a problem when I use it.
There are so many MIDs in the dump,and I want to know  MID's name.Foe example,I want to know that  /m/02mjmr is for Barack Obama,and  /m/030qb3t is for Los Angeles.
I have tried Freebase API,but there is a limited times for using it per day and is's too slow for millions of MIDs.Is there a MID-name mapping or something like that?
thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name is just another property.  In the subject/predicate/object triples that make up each line, look for the ones where the predicate is rdfs:label or Freebase's type.object.name.  In many cases, the name will be available in multiple languages for each subject.